# My code crashes when I try to update firestore database

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

My code consiste in adding events, then update the users with crated events

I have 2 main collections so far

- Events (collection) > CategoryID (document) > eventlist (collection) > eventID (document)
- Users (collection) > UserID (document)

I manage to add a new event, but when I want to add a reference of en event to a user, it crashes

Firestore reference manager

```
import Firebase

struct FirestoreReferenceManager {

    static let event = "events"

    static let db = Firestore.firestore()
    static let rootEvents = db.collection("events")
    static let rootUsers = db.collection("users")

}
```

Firestore service

```
import Firebase

class FirestoreService {

    static func addEvent(event:eventModel){

        //let eventCategory=event.eventCategory!
        //print("category to store : \(eventCategory)")

        let refEvent=FirestoreReferenceManager.rootEvents.document(event.eventCategory!).collection("eventList").document()
        let docEventId=refEvent.documentID
        let refUser=FirestoreReferenceManager.rootUsers
        let userID = String(event.eventCreator!)

        let newEvent = [
            "name":event.eventName,
            "creatorID":event.eventCreator,
            "description":event.eventDesc,
            "location":event.eventLocation,
            //"timestamp":event.eventTimestamp,
            "eventID":docEventId,
            "eventCategoryID":event.eventCategory
            ] as [String : Any]

        //Create the event
        refEvent.setData(newEvent)

        //Update the list of created events for a specific user
        refUser.document(event.eventCreator!).updateData([
            "eventsCreated" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([docEventId])
            ])
    }
}
```

Events are correctly added, but updating users with event reference But instead it just crashes. Below the logs:

Logs

```
2019-07-30 17:53:10.695944+0200 Outiz[3707:1019526]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-07-30 17:53:10.855872+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60004000 started
2019-07-30 17:53:10.855976+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2019-07-30 17:53:10.952114+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x108c00e00] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:10.952157+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x108c00e00] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:10.952253+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:10.952262+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:10.955848+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x105c17920] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:10.955884+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x105c17920] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:10.955980+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:10.955989+0200 Outiz[3707:1019542] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:11.025796+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-07-30 17:53:11.026065+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2019-07-30 17:53:11.036315+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [NetworkInfo] Could not successfully update network info for descriptor <CTServiceDescriptor 0x28198c100, domain=1, instance=2> during initialization.
2019-07-30 17:53:11.038020+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x28198c120, domain=1, instance=1>
2019-07-30 17:53:11.038480+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x28198c100, domain=1, instance=2>
2019-07-30 17:53:11.040954+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x108b015e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:11.041005+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x108b015e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:11.041123+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:11.041135+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:11.304027+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x105c34980] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:11.304609+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x105c34980] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-07-30 17:53:11.305450+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:11.305531+0200 Outiz[3707:1019535] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-07-30 17:53:11.987516+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x283ad9bd0 UIScrollView:0x109016000.width == UIVisualEffectView:0x105f09550.width   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2019-07-30 17:53:11.987878+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] Unknown class A in Interface Builder file.
2019-07-30 17:53:12.014005+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283adc640 UIScrollView:0x109016000.height == 896   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283adc550 UIScrollView:0x109016000.width == 0.462054*UIScrollView:0x109016000.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283ad9bd0 UIScrollView:0x109016000.width == UIVisualEffectView:0x105f09550.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283ae6260 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIVisualEffectView:0x105f09550.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283adc640 UIScrollView:0x109016000.height == 896   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-07-30 17:53:20.566321+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x108c07870, UIInputSetHostView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
2019-07-30 17:54:51.863695+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] -[Outiz.addEventviewControllerfirstPageViewController getData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108c04c20
2019-07-30 17:54:51.867381+0200 Outiz[3707:1019415] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Outiz.addEventviewControllerfirstPageViewController getData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108c04c20'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1baf523a8 0x1ba157d00 0x1bae6a9f8 0x1e82511d4 0x1baf57d54 0x1baf59b50 0x1ba153760 0x1e8225bf0 0x1e7ca9f94 0x1e7caa2c8 0x1e7ca92dc 0x1e7e2eb10 0x1e7e2cba0 0x1e7e2c970 0x1e825fcac 0x1e823ef50 0x1e830a150 0x1e830c90c 0x1e830cc7c 0x1e83059c4 0x1baee2444 0x1baee23c0 0x1baee1c7c 0x1baedc950 0x1baedc254 0x1bd11bd8c 0x1e82244c0 0x10267bc84 0x1ba998fd8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas ??

Thanks :)

P.S. the google service is correctly referenced, otherwise, I wouldn't be able to add any event

Comment: Towards the end, you get this `[Outiz.addEventviewControllerfirstPageViewController getData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108c04c20'`. Make sure that Outiz class contains the function mentioned in the error.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the problem. I wasn't thinking that it could be the cause since I don't call that function.